# NodeJS / Express / MongoDB - How Do I Limit Accepted Parameters in a POST Request?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoskin

I have a NodeJS server running on Express.  I am using MongoSkin to connect my web server to MongoDB.  I have the following route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/add', function(req, res){
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('products').insert(req.body, function(err){
        res.send(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The above creates an endpoint that will accept POST requests at `http://domain.com/add`.  Right now, this endpoint will save any parameters included with an AJAX request.  I have no control to limit what key / value pairs I want to save in my DB.

With PHP, you would have to explicitly look for parameters in your script to use them, ie:

```
$param1 = $.POST['param1'];
$param2 = $.POST['param2'];
$param3 = $.POST['param3'];  
// Do something with these values
```

How would I do this with NodeJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`req.body` is just an ordinary js object, so it should be exactly the same as PHP. Suppose your post request has the following values: `param1=1,param2=2,param3=invalid`. Then `req.body` will have the following form:

```
{
    param1: 1,
    param2: 2,
    param3: "invalid"    
}
```

So you just to create a new object with the values you want:

```
var allowed_params = {
    param1: req.body.param1, // Or if you prefer req.body["param1"]
    param2: req.body.param2
};
db.collection('products').insert(allowed_params, callback_func);
```

Comment: How would I allow multiple parameters in this format?

Comment: @LloydBanks exactly like the answer, req.body is just like PHP $_POST variable.

Comment: @LloydBanks If this answers your question please mark it as solved.